# Unwind segue - go back to calling view when multiple views call it

Tags: ios, swift, segue, unwind-segue

I have a view controller (in a navigation controller) A that segues to View Controller B, and View Controller C also segues to B (A -> B <- C). View Controller B is used to select a value that is passed back to either A or C, but if I click 'Cancel' or 'Done' it uses the unwind segue to go back to only one controller, whichever was connected last.

Comment: Did you implement two different unwind segues for controllers A and C?

Comment: Aaron could you provide more details? Maybe screenshots or code. It's difficult to understand what you want.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can have an unwind segue return to whichever viewController initiated the segue.  All you have to do is to implement the same method you are returning to in all of the viewControllers which segue to viewController B.

So in viewController A and viewController C, implement the following method:

```
@IBAction func backFromB(segue: UIStoryboardSegue) {
    print("Back from B")
}
```

Then, when you <kbd>Control</kbd>-drag from your *Cancel* button in viewController B to the *Exit* icon at the top of the viewController, select `backFromB` from the pop-up.

[image: drag to set up exit segue]

---

[image: choose method to return to]

---

Then when you run the app and hit *Cancel* in viewController B, you will return to either viewController A or viewController C (whichever one segued to B).  This even works if one segue is a *Show* (*Push*) and the other is *Modal*.

[image: demonstration picture]

Comment: Perfect, thanks for the quick and thorough solution.